# How do I get my secure https page to load with http sources in the html?

Tags: html, http, https, content-security-policy

I worked on a project with some other students and pulled them everyone's services together with a proxy.  We all hosted on our individual EC2 instances and everything worked fine when it was all http.  However, when I tried to put the proxy on my personal page and secure it as https, I ran into mixed-content errors.  Is there a way around this?  I don't think I can get them all to update their services to https.

I tried to specify everything allowed by placing the Content Security Policy meta tag below in the header, but still getting the errors.  The script is the service I'm trying to load.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content= "default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
script-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
connect-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; 
frame-src * data: blob: ; 
style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';
font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is and isn't HTTPS now…? You're accessing what through what?

Comment: All of the microservices are hosted on EC2 and are http.  My proxy service is pulling them all together and references them in the html body like:

<script src="http://ec2-ex-am-pl-e1.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3002/bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="http://ec2-ex-am-pl-e2.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3008/bundle.js"></script>


This works fine when hosted locally or before I attached a SSL cert to my proxy.  After attaching I get the mixed-content errors.